# Color-scheme error with print(), range(), lista() commands in Jupyterlab 4.0.3

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, color-scheme

In Jupyterlab 4.0.3 some commands like print(), range(), list(), etc are not colored with the standard color-scheme green as can be seen in the following image. In Jupyterlab version 3.x I not face this error. What may be the problem ?

[color-scheme error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLD8H.png)